# Speeding up pdf generation time

Tags: pdftex, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

- I am building a resume builder. I have mobile and web as frontend clients. I want to be able to update fonts, font colors realtime from clients. I am using node-express in backend.
- So I am generating a pdf everytime there is an update. But pdf generation is taking `900 to 1000 ms`.
- I want to improve this speed. I am using `node-latex` package to generate pdfs. The package uses `pdflatex` command.
- I saw few posts which suggest to not use `tikz` package but `tikz` is essential for my project.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Without looking at your actual code (or a dummy code which replaces your information with fake details, such as abcd for Abhishek, but has all the code you have used) it would be difficult to guess how to speed it up.

Comment: @Niranjan https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/altacv-template/trgqjpwnmtgv

Comment: Code is pretty much similar to above template as of now.

Comment: Note that we generally do not like to go off site to find example code. Links tend to rot over time, and thus your question will not be useful for others

Comment: I agree with daleif. Please provide the dummy code in the question itself.

Comment: in general you can probably make a custom format with all packages and fonts pre-loaded, see `mylatex` or `mylatexformat`

Comment: Check whether for your project you can use `pgf` directly instead of Ti*k*Z (the parsing overhead of Ti*k*Z is quite big). Also, avoid recreating the same graphics with Ti*k*Z multiple times, instead save them in boxes (check `xsavebox` for also faster and smaller PDF files).